# Matplotlib: points changing alpha mysteriously

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm working on a simple 3D animation in matplotlib within an IPython notebook, but my points are changing alpha values mysteriously:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML
import requests

%matplotlib inline

requests.get('https://gist.github.com/duhaime/023897b9bda70e7728c7db9792a11bd3/raw/b632e2ea9fb693f303908f546a684a3afcc329c0/data.npy')
X = np.load('data.npy')

def update_points(time, points):
  arr = np.array([[ X[time][i][0], X[time][i][1] ] for i in range(int(X.shape[1]))])
  points.set_offsets(arr) # set x, y values
  points.set_3d_properties(X[time][:,2][:], zdir='z') # set z value

def get_plot():
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
  ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
  ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
  ax.set_zlim(-10,10)
  points = ax.scatter(X[0][:,0][:], X[0][:,1][:], X[0][:,2][:]) # x,y,z vals
  return animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
    update_points,
    200,          # steps
    interval=100, # how often to refresh plot
    fargs=(points,),
    blit=False  
  ).to_jshtml()

HTML(get_plot())
```

Does anyone know why the points' alpha values are changing? Any suggestions others can offer would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `depthshade` argument of [Axes3d.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.scatter)

> `depthshade`  Whether or not to shade the scatter markers to give the appearance of depth. Default is True.

Set this to `False` to have no alpha changes in your plot.

Comment: Amen, thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! (Ernest is my middle name)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't explain what's mutating the alpha values, but one can mutate them back to 1 in the update function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML
import requests

%matplotlib inline

requests.get('https://gist.github.com/duhaime/023897b9bda70e7728c7db9792a11bd3/raw/b632e2ea9fb693f303908f546a684a3afcc329c0/data.npy')
X = np.load('data.npy')

def update_points(time, points):
  arr = np.array([[ X[time][i][0], X[time][i][1] ] for i in range(int(X.shape[1]))])
  points.set_offsets(arr) # set x, y values
  points.set_3d_properties(X[time][:,2][:], zdir='z') # set z value
  points.set_alpha(1)

def get_plot(lim=3):
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
  ax.set_xlim(-lim, lim)
  ax.set_ylim(-lim, lim)
  ax.set_zlim(-lim, lim)
  points = ax.scatter(X[0][:,0][:], X[0][:,1][:], X[0][:,2][:]) # x,y,z vals
  return animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
    update_points,
    200,          # steps
    interval=100, # how often to refresh plot
    fargs=(points,),
    blit=False  
  ).to_jshtml()

HTML(get_plot())
```